# How to search for cities in an area using Google Maps v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-geocoder

I tried to search for all cities within a visible map's bounds. How can I do that?

Below is what I tried to do:

```
$.fn.gmap3.geocoder.geocode({ 'address': 'Georgia' }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        globalMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var resultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest(),
            results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast()
        );
        globalMap.fitBounds(resultBounds);
        // get cities in the map
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(globalMap);
        var request = {
            bounds: resultBounds,
            types: ['locality']
        };
        service.search(request, function (results, status) {
            debugger;
        });
    }
});
```

But the result is `ZERO_RESULTS`. Maybe the reason is that the results are restricted to a radius of 50.000 meters?

Anyone knows how to solve my problem? Thanks a lot.

**--UPDATE--**

Thank, Sean, for reading my post carefully and give detail feedback.

This is how I refer to the lib:
`src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"`
I also added more detail to the geocode function to get more precise result. But I still don't get the results I want.

Check the list in this page: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types, I realize that almost all items in the first list returns values but not for the second list. The only item return value is 'political' and it returns only 1 instead of 20.

This is my code after modifing:

`this.setCenterByAddress = function (address, region) {
    $.fn.gmap3.geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address, 'region': region }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            globalMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var resultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest(),
                results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast()
            );
            globalMap.fitBounds(resultBounds);
            // get cities in the map
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(globalMap);
            var request = {
                bounds: resultBounds,
                types: ['country',
                'administrative_area_level_1',
                'administrative_area_level_2',
                'administrative_area_level_3',
                'colloquial_area',
                'country',
                'floor',
                'geocode',
                'intersection',
                'locality',
                'natural_feature',
                'neighborhood',
                'political',
                'point_of_interest',
                'post_box',
                'postal_code',
                'postal_code_prefix',
                'postal_town',
                'premise',
                'room',
                'route',
                'street_address',
                'street_number',
                'sublocality',
                'sublocality_level_4',
                'sublocality_level_5',
                'sublocality_level_3',
                'sublocality_level_2',
                'sublocality_level_1',
                'subpremise',
                'transit_station']
            };
            service.search(request, function (results, status) {
                debugger;
            });
        }
    });
}`

MORE INFO: The same value return even when location and radius is used. And I use free map and receive "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" all the time.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be limited to 50,000 meters unless you use the `location` and `radius` option, which you are not; you are using `bounds`. I suggest backing out a level and digging into the results that are returned from the starting call to `geocode`, because your usage of the `PlacesService` appears to be correct. What are the values internal to the `resultBounds` object? I also notice that you aren't using region biasing when you call the geocoder and it may be that "Georgia" is not sufficiently specific. For example, do you mean the region within the Russian Federation or the US state? And I'm not sure what URL you are using to load the Google Maps API & places library, but that could also be effecting your results.

I'd double-check the results coming back from the geocoder, because unless I am missing something, it looks like your basic approach is sound.

Comment: <pre><code><script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script></code></pre>

Comment: Since you are loading from google.com, the US is assumed as your region bias. So I would expect that you are receiving a geocode response for the US state named Georgia.

Comment: I wrote the full response but I don't know how to put here. It was deleted by the admin I think. If you don't mind, please read my comment in an unformatted way. Thanks. 


Check the list in this page: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types, I realize that almost all items in the first list returns values but not for the second list. The only item return value is 'political' and it returns only 1 instead of 20.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return more than two near by localities around a particular latitude-longitude with Geocoding API/Places API

Please see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-places-api/LWhvXkhYWi0) on Google Places API forum

> This is not possible with the Google Places API as political results
>   such as locality, neighbourhood and sublocality are returned to
>   identify the area of the request and are limited to two per request.